# How to use tzutil to get all windows time zones into an array - java

Tags: java, windows, datetime, command-line, timezone

I'm using Microsoft tzutil command to change windows 7 time zone on my java application.
tzutil has a command (tzutil /l) that displays the list of all available time zones(about 75). My application now hard coded all these time zones, I wonder if its possible to have a loop or something that iterate and insert these times zones from windows into a java array.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this question via google.
Answering in case someone else wonders how to do this.
[This Article](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2013/08/12/get-time-zone-info.aspx) provides nice info (:

Here's how to do the trick:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$timeZones = [System.timezoneinfo]::GetSystemTimeZones() | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName
foreach($timeZone in $timeZones){
    Write-Host $timeZone
}
```

Rgds!
Felix